# jQuery: filter with multiple classes

Tags: jquery, filter

Is there a nice way to accomplish filtering selected elements down to a few classes? I know I could do them one at a time, but this just seemed to be something jQuery would allow.

These are being served up with ajax, and I don't have access to define the actual html.

```
$('.val>td').each(function () {
    $(this).filter('.price,.quantity,.remove').children().children().addClass('hidetaxfields');
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to add classes directly to your tax fields, so you can select them easily for hiding?

Comment: I'm confused, are you asking if you can use `'.price,.quantity,.remove'` in `.filter()`? Since `.filter()` takes a jQuery selector, you can use a comma to separate multiple selection criteria just as you have it. It's the "Multiple Selector": http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Comment: Yes, that's the scenario I was trying. It just didn't work.

Comment: I added some explanation to my question. Sorry.

Comment: I see. It will be hard to provide a better alternative than (or fix) the one you already have if you don't provide the HTML which you're receiving.

Comment: You say you don't want to check them one at a time, but the `each` method is forcing you to do so. You should at least filter the `td`s before you run the `each`.

Comment: @BryanDowning, Good call.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

What you are asking isnt clear from the exmple you give...

This will produce a subset of the elements matched by the inital selector that have the class `one` OR `two`:

```
$(selector).filter('.one, .two');
```

This will produce a subset of the elements matched by the inital selector that have BOTH the classes `one` AND `two`:

```
$(selector).filter('.one.two');
```

Comment: The first one is what I was going for. I wonder why it didn't work?

Comment: White space is irrelevant there.

Comment: White space is irrelevant there.

Comment: True, this works perfectly for me: http://jsfiddle.net/sperske/8PZza/2/ maybe it was that '.each()' with a '.filter()' inside of it

Comment: Grrr. I just had one too many .children() on it. Sorry everyone.

Comment: You know youd probably get a performance boost if you move most of that to your initial selection instead of doing it in the loop: `$('.val > td').filter('.price,.quantity,.remove').each(function(){})` or even get it all in the selector itself: `$('.val > td.price, .val > td.quantity, .val > td.remove').each(function(){})`

Comment: Agreed. I would love to, but there is actually another part of the code that I left out when I pasted it into my question, and it needs the .each() but doesn't use the filter.

Answer (score 3):

With filter you can write a filter function that can do this like so ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sperske/8PZza/1/)):

```
$('.val>td').filter(function () {
    var that = $(this);
    return that.hasClass('price') || that.hasClass('remove') || that.hasClass('quantity');
}).addClass('hidetaxfields');
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the `.is()` method should work:

```
$('.val>td').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if( $this.is('.price, .quantity, .remove') ){
        $this.children().children().addClass('hidetaxfields');
    }
});
```

But this is even better:

```
$('.val>td.price, .val>td.quantity, .val>td.remove').each(function () {
    $(this).children().children().addClass('hidetaxfields');
});
```

or this:

```
var $tds = $('.val>td').filter('.price, .quantity, .remove');
$tds.each(function () {
    $(this).children().children().addClass('hidetaxfields');
});
```